# How to redirect URL with query string parameter in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to Request query string with parameter in show in redirect to URL like following URL but how to return write then do that 
RegNo is my string variable like abc please suggest me...

```
Url := /User/Index?abc

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Putabc()
{
   return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index","User"+"RegNo") });
}
```

Comment: `Url.Action("Index","User", new { RegNo = "abc" })`

Answer (score 1):

```
 return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index", "User", new { variableName= "abc" }) });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass only one parameter to url:

```
 public ActionResult Putabc()
 {
     return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index", "User", new { RegNo = "abc" }) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

**Result:**

[image]

If you want to pass more than one parameter to url

```
public ActionResult Putabc()
{
    return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index", "User", new { RegNo = "abc", RegName = "pqr" }) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**In Url.Action:**

The first parameter is your `actionName`.

The second parameter is your `controllerName`.

The third parameter is your `routeValues` means you can append one or more route values with this parameter.

**Edit:**

If you want to send parameter in route (`/User/Index/RegNo`) instead of query string (`/User/Index?RegNo="abc"`)

If you want to send only one parameter in route

Then you need to define one route in `RouteConfig.cs` like

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "myRouteName",
           "User/Index/{RegNo}",
           new { controller = "User", action = "Index", RegNo = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And your action method will be

```
public ActionResult Putabc()
{
    return Json(new { url = Url.RouteUrl("myRouteName", new { RegNo = "abc" }) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

If you want to send more than one parameter in route

Then you need to define one route in `RouteConfig.cs` like

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "myRouteName",
            "User/Index/{RegNo}/AnyNameHere/{RegName}",
            new { controller = "User", action = "Index", RegNo = UrlParameter.Optional, RegName = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And your action method will be

```
public ActionResult Putabc()
{
    return Json(new { url = Url.RouteUrl("myRouteName", new { RegNo = "abc", RegName = "pqr" }) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

In above both routes `User/Index/{RegNo}` or `User/Index/{RegNo}/AnyNameHere/{RegName}` you can modify as your need.

**In Url.RouteUrl:**

The first parameter is your `routeName` that is `myRouteName` in your `RouteConfig.cs`.

The second parameter is your `routeValues` means you can append one or more route values with this parameter.

Comment: @Dip Girase, please view solution might be it help you :)

Comment: no i expected following Url : /User/Index?RegNo   and RegNo is my dynamic paramteres not to fix only please suggest me how to return url then jenerated is same url

Comment: Did u mean /User/Index/RegNo like this? Then you will be able to send dynamic parameter.

Comment: @Dip Girase, view edit section in answer and let me know :)

Comment: @Dip Girase,, in my posted answer above :)

Comment: @Dip Girase, you try to edit `/User/Index?abc` like this but query string always have `key` and `value` pair

Comment: it must be `/User/Index?RegNo="abc"` got it? bcoz `RegNo` is key and `abc` is value got it?

Comment: Is the answer helpful to you?

Comment: because  this is my  another action and redirect action generate this url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177345/discussion-between-dip-girase-and-ershoaib).

Comment: @Dip, try this `public ActionResult Putabc()
        {
            string RegNo = "abc";
            string tempUrl = Url.Action("Index", "User");
            return Json(new { url = tempUrl + $"?{RegNo}" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`

Comment: the code in above comment gives you what you want means like `/User/Index?abc`

Comment: and `RegNo` is dynamic means you can send `abc` or `pqr` or `123` or `123.45M`

Comment: @Dip, does above answer and code in comment gives you what you want then accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

@Html.Raw(Url.Content("~/AspNetWebForms/ViewPDF.aspx?id=" + docID.ToString() + "&small=True"))

Comment: no , i am expected in return url on like this   /Controller/Action?parameter

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
{
    Customer data = new Customer()
    {
        CustomerID = 1,
        CustomerName = "Abcd",
        Country = "USA"
    };
    string url=string.Format("/home2/index?customerid={0}
               &customername={1}&country={2}",
               data.CustomerID,data.CustomerName,data.Country);
    return Redirect(url);
}

Comment: public string Index(string id)  
        {  
            return "ID =" + id;  
        }